# how to get a person's name on alexa?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I'm doing a project at alexa, and I want to know how do I get a person's name,
example: ask her her name and return "hello {name}"

```
"'def handle(self, handler_input):
    speech_text = 'say your name'

    handler_input.response_builder.speak(speech_text).ask(speech_text).set_card(
        SimpleCard('test', speech_text)).set_should_end_session(
        False) 
    return handler_input.response_builder.response "'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the Amazon built in slot types like AMAZON.FirstName rather than a custom slot type. Should make it easier.

Creating an intent, using a slot type, and handling slot values are all covered in most intro tutorials. If you need one, since you seem to favor Python, try this one... https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-python-first-skill

Comment: Be advised that recognizing first names very imprecise. For example, Alexa turns my first name "Christoph" into "krista", and my daughter's name "Amalie" into "emily". Your back-end will need to be able such phonetic differences.

Comment: The language for which the skill is targeted and the assumed location of the device influence ASR (Automated Speech Recognition) language models. If you're using a skill targeted to the EN-US model and the device is assumed to be in the USA, that may well be why those names (which are not common here) are being misrecognized. It's likely better to localize the skill for more regions/languages than try to predict when Emily is really Amalie as you often don't get phonetic information (or didn't 18 months ago when I left Alexa).

Comment: I am in the US but we are an international family, therefore the uncommon names ;-) After many more tries I've also been recognized as Christopher, Christophe, Kristoff, Chris and Kris. Again, IMO you can't rely on a precise match for names. In my case there is a back-end API of Alexa is only one part of. A small number of names are being entered per Amazon/Alexa account and I'll probably use the Soundex algorithm to find the closest match amongst those. For example, all those synonyms for my name result in 623, except for Kris and Chris, which is 620. Close enough.